# Trouble in hosting Facebook Apps

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I'm new to the Facebook application world and web hosting stuff.

I tested my Facebook apps locally and it runs well. However, when I try to put on my server, nothing happens, just a blank page. 
When I try to do some program without the Facebook PHP-SDK it runs well. But when I use it nothing happens.

I think this is a newbie question but I don't know where else I should put it.

I'm using xampp, in the log appears:

```
::1 - - [22/Oct/2011:19:30:15 +0100] "POST /temp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4253 "https://apps.facebook.com/first_app_diogo/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1"
```

this is locally, I see POST above, so it looks like is making a POST request, right?

My app is a canvas app.

I created a free hosting account in bytehost to put my app online, but doesn't work, I already tried with another web hosting, and had the same result. Even the simplest app that calls a the facebook API doesn't work...

I activated runtime error reporting in php and got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.' in /home/vol3/byethost7.com/b7_9378562/htdocs/php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /home/vol3/byethost7.com/b7_9378562/htdocs/php-sdk/src/facebook.php(18): require_once() #1 /home/vol3/byethost7.com/b7_9378562/htdocs/config.php(3): require('/home/vol3/byet...') #2 /home/vol3/byethost7.com/b7_9378562/htdocs/index.php(6): require('/home/vol3/byet...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/vol3/byethost7.com/b7_9378562/htdocs/php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 19
```

so, it looks like the curl extension is disabled in my server. It worked locally because I enabled the curl extension in xampp. But how do I enabled it in my free server? 
I know this isn't a programming question, but I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: You really need to either look at the server error log, or at least activate runtime error reporting in PHP. Among many other things, this could be an incompatible PHP version on the server, or just a case of a bad include path to the SDK file(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnally solved it, my free hosting provider didn't support curl, so I got another account in a different provider that supports curl. However, after that, I got the SSL problem, because since 01/10/2011 every facebook app require a SSL certificate, so I went to http://social-server.com/index/info.php in order to deliver content via SSL.
Hope this helps anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What's in your server logs? 
Is your app a canvas or page tab app?

If so, bear in mind that Facebook will send a POST request, not a GET request, when passing the `signed_request` to your application - if you were testing locally without any Facebook integration you were probably making GET requests